# React JSX "Parse Error: Unexpected identifier"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to learn React JS / JSX at the moment and have gotten stuck creating a simple login form:

```
/**
* @jsx React.DOM
*/

var loginForm = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {loggedIn : false};
    },
    login : function(event) {
        alert('logging in');
    },
    logout : function(event) {
        alert('logging out');
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form /*action={this.server+'/login.php'}*/>
                    <label htmlFor="username">Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
                    <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
                </form>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.login}> Login </button>
                <button onClick={this.logout}> Logout </button>
            </div>
        )
    }



});

React.renderComponent(
  <loginForm />,
  document.body
);
```

If I remove the `<button>` tags it works fine but otherwise an error is thrown:

`Uncaught Error: Parse Error: Line 27: Unexpected identifier`

`<button onChange={this.logout}> Logout  ...
       ^`

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4TpnG/90/

Comment: I changed your title in hopes people will find it on google easier.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're trying to return two divs from the function.  In [the docs](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/maximum-number-of-jsx-root-nodes.html) it says:

> Currently, in a component's render, you can only return one node; if
>   you have, say, a list of divs to return, you must wrap your components
>   within a div, span or any other component.
>
> Don't forget that JSX compiles into regular js; returning two
>   functions doesn't really make syntactic sense. Likewise, don't put
>   more than one child in a ternary.

So you can fix it by wrapping your two root divs in a single div; or moving your second root div (with the buttons) into the first one.

Comment: Thanks! Seems I missed this point which makes a lot of sense in terms of components->dom

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
    <form /*action={this.server+'/login.php'}*/>
            <label htmlFor="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
            <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
   </form>
   <div>
      <button onClick={this.login}> Login </button>
      <button onClick={this.logout}> Logout </button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Try using this, seems it wont work if you have two divs/nodes

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
return ([
    <div>
        <form /*action={this.server+'/login.php'}*/>
            <label htmlFor="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
            <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
        </form>
    </div>, // note the comma
    <div>
        <button onClick={this.login}> Login </button>
        <button onClick={this.logout}> Logout </button>
    </div>
]);
```